# Postman couldn't complete Oauth2 Login for Google OAuth2

Tags: postman, google-oauth

I use Google oAuth for my REST API. I used Postman to test this. It seems everything correct, but getting `"couldn't complete Oauth2 Login"` error from postman.

Google developer console

[image]

From Postman:

[image]

Im not sure what Iam doing wrong here. Please help me

**[UPDATE]** Actually I missed specify scope which is required, because the client id is created for specific scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I missed the scope which is required, because the client id is created for specific scope. After I specify the scope as below  then its working

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same issue while setting up oauth 2.0 for google APIs.

After adding scope it resolved.
Scope can be : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

FYI:
Auth URL: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes
Access Token URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
Grant Type : Authorization code.

Hope this information helps.

Answer (score -1):

there

I'm not really sure that is the same case, but we used to have something similar.

After the postman update we had problems with receiving token. The thing that helped was ***'reinstall of the postman'*** itself.

After the update they've got many issues (postman i mean).

Hope that helps.